# Merging time distributed tensor gives 'inbound node error'

Tags: merge, tensorflow, keras

In my network, I have some time distributed convolutions.Batch size = 1 image, which breaks down into 32 sub-images, for each sub-image, 3 feature of dimension 6x6x256. I need to merge all the 3 features corresponding to a particular image.

Tensor definition are like:

```
out1 = TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', activation='relu'))(out1)

out2 = TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), strides = (2,2), padding='same', activation='relu'))(out2)

out3 = TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(256, (1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu'))(out3)

out1: <tf.Tensor 'time_distributed_3/Reshape_1:0' shape=(1, 32, 6, 6, 256) dtype=float32>
out2:  <tf.Tensor 'time_distributed_5/Reshape_1:0' shape=(1, 32, 6, 6, 256) dtype=float32>
out4: <tf.Tensor 'time_distributed_6/Reshape_1:0' shape=(1, 32, 6, 6, 256) dtype=float32>
```

I have tried different techniques to merge like TimeDistributed(merge(... )), etc but nothing works.

```
out = Lambda(lambda x:merge([x[0],x[1],x[2]],mode='concat'))([out1,out2,out3])
```

It gives correct dimension tensor (1,32,6,6,768), but then it further passes through some flatten and dense layers. When i build the model like
    model = Model( .... , .... ), it gives error

File "/home/adityav/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1664, in build_map_of_graph
    next_node = layer.inbound_nodes[node_index]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'inbound_nodes'

Any idea on how to do this time distributed concatenation, when the tensors are 5dimensional.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use a simple concatenate layer? https://keras.io/layers/merge/#concatenate

Comment: @michetonu.  using concatenate also gives me correct dimension tensor (1,32,6,6,768), but this does not build the model. Probably the issue is that we cannot simply concatenate time distributed tensors. From similar concern of other people, i understand that I need to use lambda layer for some purpose, but not sure, how to implement it

Comment: I can concatenate time distributed tensors just fine using concatenate. Are you sure that's where the problem is?

Comment: Yes. I have to concatenate these three tensor(out1,out2,out3). If i forget the concatenation and just use and one of the three tensor, say 'out1' instead of 'out', then my model is build.  Only when i use concatenation, it does not work

Comment: Why does your output say ou1, out2, and out4 after the conv layers?

Comment: I just renamed them for this post, for easy of understanding over here.